Android: Show "Open link" button in notification for links
On Android When I receive a link within notification for some apps, notification previews this "Open link" button, click on it opens the link either in browser or in an app that can handle the link.
I've been going through the documentation and it seems like it's nowhere to be found.
I've already tried using notification actions, but it's just not the same.
I'd appreciate if anyone's got any hint on where to look this up.


Do you see this behavior across many devices? Can you publish a [mcve] showing your Notification containing a URL?

If I use popular apps like Whatsapp, Signal, Slack etc. they all display this "Open link" button within their notification when I receive a link in the message.
I can then click on it and android system handles the rest (opens the link in the desired app)
Unfortunately I didn't manage to reproduce it in my code, and make it work.
